# Ubuntu takes 1min22s to boot

Tags: boot, 20.04

When I first installed Ubuntu it tooks 20-25s to boot or less but now it takes constantly 1min22s to boot no matter what I do to speed up the booting process. I tried a lot of stuff to make it faster, I moved from Windows to Linux because Windows was taking 3min and now Linux is taking 1min22s, this isn't acceptable at all.

My system : Ubuntu 20.04 LTS

systemd-analyze blame output

```
31.418s plymouth-quit-wait.service                           
14.887s dev-sda3.device                                      
12.546s systemd-journal-flush.service                        
10.921s networkd-dispatcher.service                          
 9.862s fwupd.service                                        
 9.303s udisks2.service                                      
 7.479s dev-loop9.device                                     
 7.156s dev-loop2.device                                     
 7.105s dev-loop8.device                                     
 7.100s dev-loop10.device                                    
 7.013s dev-loop12.device                                    
 6.795s dev-loop11.device                                    
 6.683s dev-loop0.device                                     
 6.497s dev-loop1.device                                     
 6.496s dev-loop4.device                                     
 6.358s dev-loop13.device                                    
 6.085s polkit.service                                       
 6.051s dev-loop3.device                                     
 5.740s dev-loop6.device                                     
 5.285s dev-loop5.device                                     
 5.227s dev-loop7.device                                     
 5.132s bolt.service                                         
 4.781s avahi-daemon.service                                 
...skipping...
  164ms snap-snap\x2dstore-454.mount                         
  157ms dev-hugepages.mount                                  
  157ms dev-mqueue.mount                                     
  156ms sys-kernel-debug.mount                               
  155ms sys-kernel-tracing.mount                             
  153ms kmod-static-nodes.service                            
  142ms snap-snapd-7777.mount                                
  130ms setvtrgb.service                                     
   98ms NetworkManager.service                               
   88ms systemd-update-utmp.service                          
   66ms user-runtime-dir@1000.service                        
   66ms systemd-user-sessions.service                        
   64ms packagekit.service                                   
   54ms systemd-tmpfiles-clean.service                       
   49ms boot-efi.mount                                       
   46ms systemd-update-utmp-runlevel.service                 
   37ms rtkit-daemon.service                                 
   30ms proc-sys-fs-binfmt_misc.mount                        
   12ms plymouth-read-write.service                          
    7ms alsa-restore.service                                 
    3ms sys-fs-fuse-connections.mount                        
    2ms sys-kernel-config.mount                              
  674us snapd.socket                                         
...skipping...
  164ms snap-snap\x2dstore-454.mount                         
  157ms dev-hugepages.mount                                  
  157ms dev-mqueue.mount                                     
  156ms sys-kernel-debug.mount                               
  155ms sys-kernel-tracing.mount                             
  153ms kmod-static-nodes.service                            
  142ms snap-snapd-7777.mount                                
  130ms setvtrgb.service                                     
   98ms NetworkManager.service                               
   88ms systemd-update-utmp.service                          
   66ms user-runtime-dir@1000.service                        
   66ms systemd-user-sessions.service                        
   64ms packagekit.service                                   
   54ms systemd-tmpfiles-clean.service                       
   49ms boot-efi.mount                                       
   46ms systemd-update-utmp-runlevel.service                 
   37ms rtkit-daemon.service                                 
   30ms proc-sys-fs-binfmt_misc.mount                        
   12ms plymouth-read-write.service                          
    7ms alsa-restore.service                                 
    3ms sys-fs-fuse-connections.mount                        
    2ms sys-kernel-config.mount                              
  674us snapd.socket                                         
...skipping...
  164ms snap-snap\x2dstore-454.mount                         
  157ms dev-hugepages.mount                                  
  157ms dev-mqueue.mount                                     
  156ms sys-kernel-debug.mount                               
  155ms sys-kernel-tracing.mount                             
  153ms kmod-static-nodes.service                            
  142ms snap-snapd-7777.mount                                
  130ms setvtrgb.service                                     
   98ms NetworkManager.service                               
   88ms systemd-update-utmp.service                          
   66ms user-runtime-dir@1000.service                        
   66ms systemd-user-sessions.service                        
   64ms packagekit.service                                   
   54ms systemd-tmpfiles-clean.service                       
   49ms boot-efi.mount                                       
   46ms systemd-update-utmp-runlevel.service                 
   37ms rtkit-daemon.service                                 
   30ms proc-sys-fs-binfmt_misc.mount                        
   12ms plymouth-read-write.service                          
    7ms alsa-restore.service                                 
    3ms sys-fs-fuse-connections.mount                        
    2ms sys-kernel-config.mount                              
  674us snapd.socket
```

Comment: Look at your output: It's taking almost 15 seconds to mount /dev/sda3. You should find out why.

Comment: i assure you i have no idea if you have any suggestions pls don't hesitate